# how to get index range for zero and non-zero value from list in python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list which contains zeros and non-zero values. I want to find the range of zeros and non-zero values in terms of tuple inside the list. I am looking for package free solution with pythonic way. E.g.

```
a = [ 0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   5,  11,  12,
        12,  12,  13,  13,  17,  17,  17,  17,  17,  17,  17,  17,  17,
        25,  42,  54,  61,  61,  68,  73, 103, 115, 138, 147, 170, 187,
       192, 197, 201, 208, 210, 214, 216, 217, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221,
       222, 222, 219, 220, 220, 221, 220, 216, 216, 217, 217, 217, 217,
       216, 216, 216, 209, 204, 193, 185, 177, 161, 156, 143, 110, 103,
        89,  82,  62,  62,  62,  60,  56,  55,  50,  49,  48,  47,  47,
        45,  44,  43,  42,  40,  37,  23,  22,  14,  12,   6,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   5,
         6,   6,   6,   7,   7,   7,  13,  29,  31,  32,  33,  41,  42,
        43,  43,  44,  44,  44,  44,  44,  60,  70,  71,  72,  88,  95,
       104, 105, 111, 124, 125, 131, 145, 157, 169, 174, 186, 190, 190,
       191, 192, 192, 193, 193, 193, 194, 198, 201, 202, 203, 202, 203,
       203, 203, 203, 203, 203, 197, 195, 186, 177, 171, 154, 153, 148,
       141, 140, 135, 132, 120, 108,  94,  86,  78,  73,  60,  53,  46,
        46,  45,  44,  43,  37,  35,  29,  26,  19,  11,   0]]
```

**Output: idx = [(0,9),(10,101),(102,128),...]**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here my suggestion without external packages, short, readable and easily understandable:

```
# Compute list "b" by replacing any non-zero value of "a" with 1
b = list(map(int,[i != 0 for i in a]))

#Compute ranges of 0 and ranges of 1
idx = []   # result list of tuples
ind = 0    # index of first element of each range of zeros or non-zeros
for n,i in enumerate(b):
    if (n+1 == len(b)) or (b[n] != b[n+1]):
        # Here: EITHER it is the last value of the list 
        #       OR a new range starts at index n+1
        idx.append((ind,n))
        ind = n+1

print(idx)
```

Comment: Nice work - simplicity IS a big plus, and well done for including comments.

Comment: as per your first comment, I cant replace it with **one** as values are a summation of a horizontal value of the matrix.There might be a chance that I will get "1" as a summation value which will change the meaning of future computation.

Comment: @Zara My suggestion does not change the values of your original list named `a`. It creates another temporary list that I named `b` to compute the list of tuples. So it should be OK for you.

Comment: @Zara Regarding your comment on another answer to add the zero / non-zero value, you can use `idx.append((ind,n, str(b[n])))` instead of `idx.append((ind,n))`. Still simple !

Answer (score 2):

You could `enumerate()` to get the indexes, `itertools.groupby()` to group falsy (`0`) and truthy values together, and extract the start and end indexes with `operator.itemgetter(0, -1)`:

```
from operator import truth, itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

[itemgetter(0,-1)([i for i,v in g]) for _, g in groupby(enumerate(a), key = lambda x: truth(x[1]))]
# [(0, 9), (10, 101), (102, 128), (129, 217), (218, 252), (253, 338), (339, 362), (363, 447), (448, 490), (491, 580), (581, 581)]
```

Comment: If shortness were the only objective then this is a clear winner, BUT I have no idea how it works, and by being a one-liner there is (by definition) no opportunity to include comments to explain to a code reviewer how it works. That's one-liners for you, hey?

Comment: @barny Well I did include an explanation above, I suggest you you refer to the documentation of `enumerate`, `itertools` and `operator`, but if you have any specific questions I'd be happy to try and answer them here :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer without an external library:

```
pointer = 0
is_zero = True
result = []


def finder(p, is_z):
    while (a[p] == 0) is is_z:
        p += 1
        if p == len(a):
            return p
    return p


while pointer < len(a):
    tmp = finder(pointer, is_zero)
    result.append((pointer, tmp - 1))
    pointer = tmp
    is_zero = not is_zero
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

No imports needed (so no need to search the library docs to work out how those imports work :-) and with comments.

```
# results is the output list, each entry is a list of startindex,stopindex
results = []
# each time round the logical value is remembered in previouslvalue
previouslvalue = None
for i,value in enumerate(a):
    # get the logical value (==0/!=0) from value
    lvalue = True if value != 0 else False
    if previouslvalue is None or lvalue != previouslvalue:
        # this is either the first entry, or the lvalue has changed
        # either way, append a new entry to results, with the current index as start/finish of the run
        results.append([i,i])
    else:
        # same lvalue as previous, extend the last entry to include this index
        results[-1][1] = i
    # save the logical value for next time round the loop
    previouslvalue = lvalue
print results
```

Output is:

```
[[0, 9], [10, 101], [102, 128], [129, 217], [218, 252], [253, 338], [339, 362], [363, 447], [448, 490], [491, 580], [581,581]]
```

Responding to comment about including the logical value in the results list, this is very easy:

```
# results is the output list, each entry is a list of startindex,stopindex
results = []
# each time round the 
previouslvalue = None
for i,value in enumerate(a):
    # get the logical value (==0/!=0) from value
    lvalue = True if value != 0 else False
    if previouslvalue is None or lvalue != previouslvalue:
        # this is either the first entry, or the lvalue has changed
        # either way, append a new entry to results, with the current index as start/finish of the run
        # include the logical value in the list of results
        results.append([i,i,lvalue])
    else:
        # same lvalue as previous, extend the last entry to include this index
        results[-1][1] = i
    # save the logical value for next time round the loop
    previouslvalue = lvalue
print results
```

Output is now:

```
[[0, 9, False], [10, 101, True], [102, 128, False], [129, 217, True], [218, 252, False], [253, 338, True], [339, 362, False], [363, 447, True], [448, 490, False], [491, 580, True], [581, 581, False]]
```

Comment: Your approach is very good. I gave thought to this similar logic but I am not able to make it possible in code. Is it possible that I can add index range with zero and non-zero value? e.g. [(0,9,'0'),(10,101,'1'),(102, 128,'0'),...]

Comment: That is very easy, simply change `results.append([i,i])` to `results.append([i,i,lvalue])` - see edited answer

Answer (score -2):

```
import numpy as np 

unique, counts = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
idx = tuple(zip(unique, counts))
```

I think this will work for you.

Comment: this doesn't seem to match the OP's expected output

Comment: this gives the same output as `collections.Counter`.